# Obtaining IPv6 configuration state

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'm writing some code to return the state of my IPv6 configuration. Is there a linux system script ( or C/C++ functions) i can call to return the state of my IPv6. For instance, something like, Auto, Manual or DHCPv6 would be 3 possible states. There must be some flag to determine this. I've been looking at

```
ip -f inet6 addr show eth0 scope global | grep inet6
```

and although the scope indicates dynamic, is this the flag that may change in response to changing the ipv6 conf. It outputs

```
inet6 <ipv6 addr> scope global deprecated dynamic
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to figure out whether the interface was configured manually, using automatic configuration, or using DHCP...you're not going to be able to get that information from the interface.  Generally, an interface doesn't know *how* it was configured; that information is encoded in your system's network configuration.

For example, a system using DHCP acquires a lease from the DHCP server and then calls `ifconfig` or `ip` to configure the interface.  This is *indistinguishable* from manually configuring the interface.

Under RedHat-ish systems, you can look in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` for that information.  The `ifcfg-*` files containing a series of shell variables that define the configuration.  For example, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` on my system contains:

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
```

Under Debian-ish systems, you can find similar information in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/network` is nowhere to be seen on my system.

Comment: Maybe I meant /etc/network/interfaces?  It was three years ago.  In any case, Ubuntu now has some good documentation on IPv6 that is probably of more use: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6